# Write a program that reads an unspecified number of integers

Tags: java

"Count positive and negative numbers and compute the average of numbers) Write a program  that reads an unspecified number of integers , determines how many positive and negative values  have been read, and computes the total and average of the input values  (not counting zeros). Your program  ends with the input 0. Display the average as a floating-point number."

I don't know what I did wrong

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int positive = 0, negative = 0, total = 0, count = 0;

        double average;

        System.out.println("Enter the number: ");
        int number;

        while ((number = input.nextInt()) != 0) {
            total += number;
            count++;
            if (number > 0) {
                positive++;
            } else if (number < 0) {
                negative++;
            }
        }
        average = total / count;
        System.out.println("The number of positives is " + positive);
        System.out.println("The number of negatives is " + negative);
        System.out.println("The total is " + total);
        System.out.printf("The average is %d ", average);
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: To help better your question, please include expected and achieved output, otherwise it's find the error in the haystack and people don't like that game.

Comment: If you indented your code correctly you would see that you have an extra curly brace at the end.

Answer (score 3):

First: it should be `average = (double)total / count;` because int / int than you get an integer.

Second: `System.out.println("The average is " + average);` or `System.out.printf("The average is %f ", average);`

Answer (score 2):

If you want the average of numbers, you cannot divide an integer `total` by an integer `count` because the result will be an integer, which does not account for decimal points.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int positive = 0, negative = 0, total = 0, count = 0;

        double average;

        System.out.println("Enter the number: ");
        int number;

        while ((number = input.nextInt()) != 0) {
            total += number;
            count++;
            if (number > 0) {
                positive++;
            } else if (number < 0) {
                negative++;
            }
        }
        average = (double) total / count;
        System.out.println("The number of positives is " + positive);
        System.out.println("The number of negatives is " + negative);
        System.out.println("The total is " + total);
        System.out.printf("The average is: " + average);
    }
}
```

Also, you don't have to use %d in your line `System.out.printf("The average is %d", average);`

You can write `System.out.printf("The average is: " + average);` because when you print out a String, anything concatenated within the parentheses will also be converted to a String, and printed out as such

Comment: "If you want the average of numbers, you cannot divide an integer total by an integer count because..." Well, actually, you can do exactly that, and if the sum is sufficiently large relative to the count, then the resulting integer value might be close enough to the actual average for some application.  If, on the other hand, the sum could be relatively small, or if you don't have enough information to compute how large the sum needs to be, then you'd probably be better off doing it with floating point (double) arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Simply multiply your int variable by 1.0 to convert it into floating point variable
    `average=1.0*total/count;`
This should do.
And you can use following statement to display the value 
`System.out.println("The average of numbers is "+average);`

Answer (score 0):

```
// Scanner is in java.util package
import java.util.Scanner;
class CountPandN
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // create a Scanner object
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // prompt user to enter numbers
        System.out.println("Enter + and - numbers");
        System.out.println("Enter 0 when you're finished");
        // initialize the variables
        int n, countP, countN, count;
        n = input.nextInt();
        countP = 0;
        countN = 0;
        count = 0;
        int sum = n;
        float average = (float) sum / 2;

        while (n != 0)
        {
            n = input.nextInt();
        count++;

        if(n >= 0)
            countP++;
        if (n < 0)
            countN++;
        }
        System.out.println("Total positive " + countP);
        System.out.println("Total negative " + countN);
        System.out.println("Total numbers " + count);
        System.out.println("Total average " + average);
    }
}
```

Comment: It should give you the exact answer that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

if you simply change `System.out.printf("The average is %d ", average);` with           `System.out.printf("The average is  " +average);` i.e. if you remove`%d` and use `'+'`instead `','` then it will work for you, and also to get answer in float you need to use typecasting. i.e. add `(double)` in  `average = (double)total / count;`